# Removing part of image in photoshop

Tags: photoshop

I have this element in my psd layout

[image]

I need to remove green rectangle and leave a gray box with a gap at the top (in place of the green rectangle) and save as .png.  How can I remove green rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

1. select `Magic Wand Tool` (press `W` on keyboard), then select the
   green area and then press `Backspace` to remove it.
2. Then Create new Layer with white background and set it as background
   layer,
3. Then create your own gray layer.

Comment: `Magic Wand Tool` is impossible because it's a group :(

Comment: can you upload your image in another place, i can't access to url because of filtering :(